# Prime Number with Simple for loop not working?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, math, primes

Im trying to solve a problem where I have to use a for loop in solving if a number is prime or not. It seems like it only picks up if the number is divided by two to determine if it is prime or not. My code doesn't pick up if it is divisible by 3 and up though...

Here is my code:

```
def isPrime(num):
  for i in range (2,num):
    if (num%i) !=0:
      return True
    else:
      return False


isPrime(15)
```

I know 15 is not a prime number but it is returning `True` instead of `False`. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Don't you mean 15 "isn't" a prime number?  Also, if when ```num = 15```, and ```i``` is 2,  you're going to get  ```if (15 % 2) != 0:```   Which is true and then it returns ```True```.

Comment: Right  correct, Let me edit the question now

Comment: I'd expect `for i in range (2,num-1):` or `for i in range (2,num/2):` or `for i in range (2,isqrt(num)):`

Comment: [Pythontutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) is a great tool helping you to understand why small programs do not behave as you expect. What does (15%2) return in the first loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's *algorithm* always exits on the first iteration.

Instead, loop less often and only exit loop when a divisor is found.  Also account for values less than 2.

```
def isPrime(num):
  for i in range [2,isqrt(num)]:
    if (num%i == 0) return False
  
  if (num < 2) return False
  return True
```

Comment: `return num ≥ 2`